# How should I be placing my server?

Tags: nas

I am looking to buy an old HP server on eBay, I have found what I want and everything but wanted to have some advice on the placement of the server.

It is a rack mount server, and I have read some other posts, but was wondering if there are any other factors as to whether it should be in a rack.

It will have its full 8 hard drives in (so its maximum amount of drives), and I was thinking of mounting it to a wall with brackets that have some kind of vibration absorption on to slightly decrease any vibrations. The server is not primarily a storage server, but that will definitely be one of its functions.

My friend told me that the vibrations would be an issue, and that would be the purpose and the reason that I should get a server rack. Is this really needed, advised, or maybe just an unnecessary measure for a home server?

Literally any other advice about my journey in buying a server would be useful.
Thanks in advance, Zak.

Answer (score 1):

It's really not necessary, the 8 drives won't give that many vibrations. There are normal cases with 10 drives and nothing to absorb it for example. I'm using a 10-drive case for a home server and I've never had any problems with it. For servers with less then say 20 drives, the rack is just a way to storage the rack-switches, routers and servers in one convenient way.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'd like a few more opinions but this basically goes alongside what I was kinda thinking. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

We place all our client servers in racks along with the server disk arrays. Vibration is not a problem and has not been over the long time we have done this.

An extra rack to preclude vibration is not needed in the majority of cases

Comment: The question was "do I need a rack". I don't think you've answered this question.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify